# Sqlite in dead lock state when deleting records from the same table from different threads

Tags: c++, database, multithreading, sqlite

We are using the sqlite 3.7.14.1 code in our application.  Lately we are seeing a dead lock kind of state while deleting records from a table. The deletion is done from two different threads and acting upon the same table.

Sqlite is configured in WAL mode. All threads open their own shared connection to the database. The application is complied with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 and SQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT.

```
m_init = sqlite3_open_v2(
            m_dbfilename.toUtf8().data(),                                                                   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
            &m_dbHandler,                                                                                   /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
            SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX | SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE,    /* Flags */
            NULL                                                                                             /* Name of VFS module to use */
            );
```

All update,insert and  deletion of records in multiple threads happen in transactions. The update/insert statement works absolutely fine with out any dead lock. But when two or more threads try to remove an  entry in the same table, then they go into a dead lock state where sqlite3_step keeps on returning SQLITE_LOCKED. When we did debug the code

```
10:00.234 Thread 1 BEGIN
10:00.235 Thread 1 select * from <table1>
10:00.234 Thread 1 select * from <table x>
10:00.456 Thread 1 delete from <table1>

10:00.456 Thread 2 BEGIN
10:00.456 Thread 2 select * from <table1>
10:00.906 Thread 2 select * from <table x>
10:01.156 Thread 2 delete from  <table1>

Thread 1 SQLITE_LOCKED(6) Error <Table1> is locked
Thread 2 SQLITE_LOCKED(6) Error database table is locked
```

Thread 1 which is the first one to enter BEGIN and do modifications to the table, and it should have gained the WRITE lock on the table. Even If we consider Thread 2 was performing the select on the same table at the same time, then Thread 2 should have locked table in its delete call. In this case none of the threads are getting lock on the table and are waiting for ever. In each of the thread we are waiting for a random amount of time re-executing(sqlite3_step) the same prepared statement after calling reset on the prepared statement.

In any of the scenario one of the thread should be the winner in getting the lock on this table.

My question is how can I find who is locking the table. Is there any way I can get this info ? why is this happening for delete when concurrent update and inserts are happening properly ?